# Polynomial interpolation with evenly spaced data.

Tags: numerical-methods

Given the following data table,

x   1.20    1.25    1.3 1.35    1.40    1.45    1.50
f(x)    0.1823  0.2231  0.2624  0.3001  0.3365  0.3716  0.4055

```
What degree of polynomial required to exactly fit all 7 points to within 3 significant digits?
```

I want to know the systematic approach to this question, if there is any. I’m also aware of the fact that to fit a polynomial through all seven points require an interpolating polynomial of degree less than or equal to 6, as there are 7 points. But the additional requirement that it has to be within 3 significant digits is something which I’m not so sure about how to deal with.
I have initially tried bounding the error formula by (0.5 x 10^-03) and solve for n (the degree of interpolating polynomial), but I’ve reached dead end.

Here is my initial trial of bounding the error formula by (0.5 x 10^-03),

I’ve started out using the error formula
E_n (x)=|f(x)-p_n (x)|≤1/(n+1)!  |f^((n+1) ) (ζ)|  1/4  n!h^(n+1)<0.5 ×〖10〗^(-3)
And since f(x) is a linear function as can be seen from the given data table, I then decided to approximate the derivate using

max┬(x_k≤x≤x_(k+1) )⁡〖|f^" (x)|≈{|(f(x_(k-1) )-2f(x_k )+f(x_(k+1) ))/h^2 |,|(f(x_k )-2f(x_(k+1) )+f(x_(k+2) ))/h^2 |}〗
From which I obtained |D_2 |=6.4 ×〖10〗^(-3) as the approximation to the derivative, then the error formula becomes

E_n (x)=|f(x)-p_n (x)|≤1/(n+1)!  |D_2 |  1/4  n!h^(n+1)<0.5 ×〖10〗^(-3)
E_n (x)=|f(x)-p_n (x)|≤n!/(n+1)!  (6.4 × 〖10〗^(-3))1/4  〖(0.5)〗^(n+1)<0.5 ×〖10〗^(-3)

n!/((n+1).n!)  (6.4 × 〖10〗^(-3))1/4  (0.5)^n (0.5)<0.5 ×〖10〗^(-3)
1/((n+1) )  〖(0.5)〗^n<0.625

ln⁡[〖(0.5)〗^n/((n+1) )]

〖n(ln〗⁡0.5)-ln⁡〖(n+1)

〖n(ln〗⁡0.5)-max┬(0≤n≤6)⁡{ln⁡〖(n+1)〗 }⁡〖2.1293.

Is this a valid idea/approach? Or can anyone help me out here by solving this question using a systematic approach?

Comment: Do you know about linear programming?

Comment: Can you explain the significance of, "within 3 significant digits " in the question? And What polynomial of lesser degree will almost fit to the same precision? Justify your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what if I construct a table of ordinary differences and use its entries together with the next term rule to estimate the accuracy of the required polynomial to within 3 significant digits? From the table it would also be easy to see the degree of the required polynomial as well. Pretty sure that will work out well :)